# Email Current URL in Mobile Safari / Android

Tags: javascript, android, mobile

Does anyone know a way I can provide a link in HTML for users to click on which would open their device's mail reader with a pre-written subject line and a blank "To:" field?

The idea is to let users mail the URL of a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=Subjet here&body=Body of email here">Email me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=Your+subject">Your text</a>
```

Reference: http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html